# Typing special characters in terminal

Tags: command-line, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I want to be able to type a special character (é) in terminal.
I found a webpage which tells me to push a dead_acute key along with "e" key and that's it.

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libX11/plain/nls/en_US.UTF-8/Compose.pre

< dead_acute> < e>                  : "é"   eacute # LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE

Easier said than done, because I looked everywhere which is actually the < dead_acute> key , --- at least the default one, but I couldn't find it.

Could you tell me which is (default) dead_acute key?

Answer (score 1):

For a german keyboard layout, two are typically on the key to the left of backspace key, the circumflex accent is typically on the key to the right (or on some keyboards below) of escape key.

Now keep in mind that for them to actually work, you need a keyboard layout that has dead keys active (most germans for example use the 'nodeadkeys' layout as default, because we dont need those accents usually).

If you have a nodeadkeys layout active, those keys will immediately print without the chance to 'attach' to another character, if you dont have a nodeadkeys layout, the only way to print them alone (not attached to a character) is press the dead key followed by a whitespace.

Comment: As Element82 is from the UK: the dead_acute key is [Alt Gr]' (single quote) on a UK keyboard.